# Legend does not work for scatter plot in Octave

Tags: octave, legend, scatter

I am trying to draw a scatter plot in Octave 5.1.0 and the legend sometimes does not work.

I import data from external files, scatter some part of data and add a legend. Only a horizontal line is displayed instead of a full legend box. I don't understand why, since I created a similar plot several weeks ago with a different data set, and it worked correctly.

Also it works with fltk, but does not work with gnuplot. However, I need exactly gnuplot to use Russian symbols.

```
clf
graphics_toolkit ("gnuplot")
set (0, "defaultaxesfontname", "Arial") 

load cryo.dat
load hy2a.dat
load sent.dat
load saral.dat
load ja2.dat
load ja3.dat

subplot(3,1,1)
hold on
scatter(cryo(:,1),cryo(:,2),40,[0.6 0.6 0.6],'s','filled')
legend("CRYOSAT2","location","northeast")
```

Several first strings of cryo.dat file:

```
57754.985   0.82
57755.999   0.96
57756.999   0.93
57757.999   1.04
57758.999   0.83
57759.999   0.97
57760.999   0.9
57761.999   0.93
57762.999   0.93
57763.999   0.96
57764.999   0.94
57765.999   0.95
57766.999   0.94
57767.999   0.86
57768.999   0.92
57769.999   0.97
57770.999   0.97
57771.999   0.98
57772.999   0.88
57773.999   0.84
57774.999   0.92
57775.999   0.85
57776.999   0.9
```

I am also able to reproduce it with rand function:

```
test(:,1) = rand(100,1)
test(:,2) = rand(100,1)

subplot(3,1,1)
hold on
scatter(test(:,1),test(:,2),40,[0.6 0.6 0.6],'s','filled')
legend('test','location','northeastoutside')
grid on
```

Comment: Ideally you'd post a [mre]. Maybe you're able to recreate the problem by creating a data set with `rand`. If not, could you at least provide some characteristics of `cryo`?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Cryo is data set for a satellite - Modified Julian Date plus measurement residual. I have added several lines of the file into the description

Comment: Also I am able to reproduce it with rand function, added it to the initial description